# Syntax for array of nested composite type without using ARRAY[]

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE TYPE pencil_count AS(
    pencil_color varchar(30),
    count integer
);

CREATE TYPE pencil_count_with_date(
date_ date,
pencil_count pencil_count[]
);

CREATE TABLE pencils(id serial, pencils_ pencil_count_with_date[]);

INSERT INTO pencils(pencils_) 
VALUES('{"(\"2016-03-13\",{"(\"blue\",1)","(\"red\",2)"})"}');
```

What would be the correct syntax if I want to add this composite array without using `ARRAY[...]`?

Comment: please add some `;` to your first two commands. DDL needs semicolons, too ...

Comment: (1) Why don't you want to use `array[...]`, that makes everything so much easier. (2) Isn't this the same thing as [your other question recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35955943/479863)?

Comment: @mu is too short not quite I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using literal string will be less readable when you add new nested levels:

```
CREATE TYPE pencil_count AS(pencil_color varchar(30)
       ,"count" int);

CREATE TYPE pencil_count_with_date AS(date_ date
                                     ,pencil_count pencil_count[]);

CREATE TABLE pencils(id serial, pencils_ pencil_count_with_date[]);

INSERT INTO pencils(pencils_) 
VALUES('{"(
               \"2016-03-13\",
               \"{
                   \"\"(Blue,5)\"\",
                   \"\"(Red,2)\"\"
               }\"
          )"}');   


SELECT pencils_[1].pencil_count[1].pencil_color
FROM pencils;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/39b9e/1/0)**</kbd>

Remarks:

1. You need to quote each level with `"` escaped by [`\`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) based on nest level.
2. This kind of schema looks like trying to introduce OO world to databases. It could be harder to maintain and slower than normalized version. [Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225397/postgresql-insert-an-array-of-composite-type-containing-arrays)
3. You could quote string literals with [`$$`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) if needed.
4. Using `ARRAY` and `ROW` could be easier to spot where each level starts and stops.

Answer (score 1):

Again, ask Postgres. Extending on the procedure for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35955943/939860):

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE pencil_count (
  pencil_color varchar(30)
, count integer
);

CREATE TABLE pencil_count_with_date (
  date_ date
, pencil_count pencil_count[]
);

CREATE TABLE pencils (
  id serial
, pencils_ pencil_count_with_date[]
);
```

Ask Postgres for each nested level:

```sql
INSERT INTO pencil_count VALUES ('red' , 1), ('blue', 2);

SELECT ARRAY(SELECT p FROM pencil_count p)::text AS p_row_arr;

-- with result from above:
INSERT INTO pencil_count_with_date(date_, pencil_count)
VALUES ('2016-04-14', '{"(red,1)","(blue,2)"}')
     , ('2016-04-14', '{"(red,3)","(blue,4)"}');

SELECT ARRAY(SELECT p FROM pencil_count_with_date p)::text AS p2_row_arr;

-- with result from above:
INSERT INTO pencils(pencils_)
VALUES
  ('{"(2016-04-14,\"{\"\"(red,1)\"\",\"\"(blue,2)\"\"}\")"
    ,"(2016-04-15,\"{\"\"(red,3)\"\",\"\"(blue,4)\"\"}\")"}');

SELECT id, pencils_::text FROM pencils;
```

Result:

```
id | pencils_
---+-------------------------------------------------------
1  | {"(2016-04-14,\"{\"\"(red,1)\"\",\"\"(blue,2)\"\"}\")"
     ,"(2016-04-15,\"{\"\"(red,3)\"\",\"\"(blue,4)\"\"}\")"}
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KZ5ud5_L)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3eb64/1)</sub>

I fully agree with advice so far: Multiple levels of nested row types is typically complex and inefficient. Consider normalization.

More in my answer to your previous question:

- [Correct syntax for array of composite type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955943/correct-syntax-for-array-of-composite-type/35979476#35979476)

Comment: Is it alright if we use array of nested composite to pass as input parameters to postgresFunction and insert them into normalised tables? Appreciate if there is an example. Example - Each Shipment has multiple Shipment Items and multiple Contact address. We would like to load up 100 shipments in one postgres function call.